# Apple App Provisioning Profiles

Tags: provisioning-profile

> ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.haltonhills.businessdiretory [Business Directory] is invalid. [Expired profile.] For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."

How do I renew my Provisioning Profile and Code-signing certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Log into the Apple Developer site (https://developer.apple.com) and go to the section Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles.  Go to the Provisioning Profiles section, find the provisioning profile for your app ID, and you should be able to re-generate a new one. If the certificate is expired as well, you'll need to generate a new one before it will let you generate a new provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

For renew the certificate you have to create a new certificate.

For renew of the provisioning you have to modify the provisioning file on the Apple Developer website and select the new certificate.

The expiration date is the same date as the expiration date of the certificate

[image]

Comment: Just a note, the provisioning profiles duration can be at most 1 year, where a certificate can be valid for 3 years, so they often will have different expiration dates. If the certificate is going to expire in less than 1 year, the provisioning profile will also expire on the cert expiration date, since the profile cannot be valid after the certificate is no longer valid.